Problem to deal with some ERC20 Tokens on Polygon-PoS (USDC, USDT) using Web3.py + Uniswap V3
gm. This is my first post here, i will do my best to be specific.
I started to work and build some python scripts to automate some operations on Polygon-PoS network.
I have the following working:(each one is a script)

WRAP MATIC into WMATIC
UNWRAP WMATIC into MATIC
Check token approval
Get token name and symbol
Retrieve and save ABI from contracts
APPROVE token contract to spend in our behalf
SWAP one token in exchange to another one

The swap function(last one) I am having issues with some ERC20 tokens like:

USDC = 0x3c499c542cEF5E3811e1192ce70d8cC03d5c3359 # Metamask USDC on Polygon PoS
USDT = 0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F # Metamask USDT on Polygon PoS

These tokens(USDC,USDT) do not have the approve function like others:

SFL    = 0xD1f9c58e33933a993A3891F8acFe05a68E1afC05 # Metamask SFL    on Polygon PoS
WETH   = 0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619 # Metamask WETH   on Polygon PoS
WMATIC = 0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270 # Metamask WMATIC on Polygon PoS

I can manage properly SFL, WETH and WMATIC. I can SWAP WMATIC to USDC but i can not SWAP USDC to any other token. What I am missing here? Can anyone explain to me how can i  deal with these tokens that are not like the others listed here?
I tried to manage them like i did with WMATIC, WETH, SFL and others but they dont accept the same commands/functions. All transactions that i sent to blockchain fail. I can not debug deeper.
Thanks in advance.

Could you share a reproducible code of the swap for  WMATIC/USDC and the attempt and errors you encountered with swap USDC to other tokens?

You haven't left any code here but ill tell you what trips up everyone first starting.  The forget about the first approval.  They write a contract which executes the swap and approves the router to spend from their contract,  But when testing they forget that the contract they deployed needs to be approved to spend tokens from the users wallet.
